# can the wcsncpy_s function result in a buffer overflow?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, buffer-overflow

I'm trying to understand how the wcsncpy_s function works and how it prevents against buffer overflows. First, according to MSDN, the arguments to this function mean the following:

strDest=    Destination string.

numberOfElements=    The size of the destination string.

strSource=    Source string.

count=    Number of characters to be copied, or _TRUNCATE.

Now consider this code:

```
wchar_t a[5];
wcsncpy_s(a, 10, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);

printf("%d\r\n", sizeof(a));//10
printf("%d\r\n", wcslen(a));//9
wprintf(L"%s", a);//ABCDEFGHI
```

If I am making sense of all this, "a", which is supposed to hold at most 4 wide characters plus a null terminator, now holds 9 wide characters.

Now, the following code will cause my app to terminate abruptly due to a failed debug assertion (VS 2005 compiler):

```
wchar_t a[5];
wcsncpy_s(a, 10, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 10);

printf("%d\r\n", sizeof(a));
printf("%d\r\n", wcslen(a));
wprintf(L"%s", a);
```

Can someone please explain the code above and also how wcsncpy_s is supposed to prevent against buffer overflows?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
wcsncpy_s(a, 10, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
```

You are lying to the function.  You tell it, "`a` has sufficient space to store 10 characters," when in fact it has only enough space to store five.  The function trusts that you are providing it with valid information (how could it know that you aren't?)

Note that while you get a runtime error with the second code snippet, the first code snippet is equally wrong.  Both write past the end of the array `a`.

That said:  you are using the wrong overload of `wcsncpy_s`:  when compiling C++ code, there is an additional `wcsncpy_s` overload that is a template that deduces the size of the target array.  If you were to change the call to:

```
wcsncpy_s(a, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
```

The template will deduce that the array has five elements and automatically use that as the size.  This works only when the target is an array; it does not work if the target is a pointer to the initial element in an array.

Ideally, if you are using C++, it is best to avoid C string manipulation altogether:  use `std::wstring`  or some other string type.  If you do want to use these functions that work with C strings, at least use `std::vector<wchar_t>` or `std::array<wchar_t, N>` instead of raw arrays:  it's much harder to screw up the code.  For example,

```
std::array<wchar_t, 5> a;
wcsncpy_s(a.data(), a.size(), L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
```

The code for `std::vector<wchar_t>` would be identical.  Note that obtaining a pointer to the underlying array and obtaining the size of that array follow the same form, so it's both easy to write the code and easy to check that the code is correct (simple visual inspection of the invocation is all that is required).

Comment: +1:The overload, provided by a template deduction, works fantastic for fixed size buffers of compile-time size determination (i.e. arrays of X[]). For buffers that you allocate yourself, including in such things as stl sequences like vector<> and string<> objects, you must provide the length parameter. The compiler will tell when, as providing a non-fixed sequence for the target without specifying the length will generate a compiler error.

Comment: James, isn't the second argument supposed to represent the size of the destination buffer? That's what MSDN says

Comment: @JohnSmith:  No, the name of the second parameter is `numberOfElements`.  The number of elements is the same as the size for arrays of `char` (because `sizeof(char) == 1`) but not for `wchar_t` (because `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` using Visual C++).

Comment: I can now see what I was doing wrong. and I also learned that the MSDN documentation is misleading: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43%28VS.80%29.aspx. So the answer to the original question is "yes, a secure function can result in a buffer overflow if you use it incorrectly"

Comment: @JohnSmith:  Always use [the latest documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5dae5d43.aspx).  The documentation to which you linked is from Visual C++ 2005 (i.e., it's seven years old).  We've substantially improved the documentation since then.  You can select the documentation version from the drop-down at the top of the page; it says "Other Versions."  The current documentation says that the second parameter is "The size of the destination string, in characters."

Comment: But, yes, violating the preconditions of any runtime function causes your program to yield undefined behavior.

Comment: @JohnSmith: the purpose of the 'secure', bounds-checking interfaces isn't to be secure in the face of incorrect arguments, it's to make it so the function has the information it needs to respect buffer boundaries and to provide the capability of centralized error handling.

Comment: _TRUNCATE will only copy the amount of data that can be stored inside the destination....

Answer (score 4):

In this line:

```
wcsncpy_s(a, 10, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 9);
```

you're telling the function that there is room for `10` characters in `a`, when in fact there is only room for `5`.

Answer (score 2):

the definition of wcsncpy_s is

```
errno_t wcsncpy_s(
wchar_t *strDest,
size_t numberOfElements,
const wchar_t *strSource,
size_t count 
);
```

strDest is the buffer your writing too.

numberOfElements is how many elements are inside the strDest buffer.

strSource is the buffer you are reading from

count is the number of elements in strSource to copy to strDest

so in

```
wchar_t a[5];
wcsncpy_s(a, 10, L"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 10); //ERROR

printf("%d\r\n", sizeof(a));
printf("%d\r\n", wcslen(a));
wprintf(L"%s", a);
```

wchar_t is 2 characters wide.

The problem is that the function automatically writes a null terminator for you at the end. This causes an overflow cause its trying to write one past the end.

wcsncpy_s isnt helping you with this error because you told it that there were 10 elements available in a. when there are in fact only 5 elements available.